# FPDF different name in firefox then chrome

Tags: php, firefox, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to create a PDF in PHP. This works fine in Chrome, but doesn't work properly in Firefox.

I'm guessing Firefox is getting this extra number from the URL? This is NOT a big problem, but I would like it to be consistent across browsers. Here is my code:

```
$pdf = new Fpdf();
$pdf->setTitle("Order-$id");
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE);
```

Chrome
[image: Chrome]
Firefox
[image: Firefox]

Comment: I'm pretty sure firefox is suffixing the title with the filename of the PDF sent as an attachment.

Comment: FF adds the name of the actual program being run to the title while Chrome doesn't. I'm pretty sure there is not a way to change the behavior of FF.